# Jquery setTimeout throwing an " JScript runtime error: Invalid argument." exception?

Tags: jquery, validation, settimeout, copy-paste

I wrote the following code for wordcount validation for pasting text/key press into a textarea:

```
  $('textarea[maxlength]').keyup(function(eventObject) {
              window.setTimeout(validateLength(eventObject.target), 1);
              return true;
```

The validateLength function (below) gets exceuted, but an exception is thrown when it returns to settimeout:

```
 function validateLength(textareaElement) {
           //get the limit from maxlength attribute
                var limit = parseInt($(textareaElement).attr('maxlength'));
                //get the current text inside the textarea
                var text = $(textareaElement).val();
                //count the number of characters in the text
                var chars = text.length;

                //check if there are more characters then allowed
                if(chars > limit){
                    //and if there are use substr to get the text before the limit
                    var new_text = text.substr(0, limit);

                    alert('The character limit is ' + limit + '. Your text has been trimmed to ' + limit + ' characters.');
                    //and change the current text with the new text
                    $(textareaElement).val(new_text);
                }
                alert(chars);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function and passing the result to setTimeout. You need to pass a function.

```
$('textarea[maxlength]').keyup(function(eventObject) {
  window.setTimeout(function(){validateLength(eventObject.target)}, 1);
  return true;
}
```